# How to revert an insertAfter in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, insertafter

This is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function OrderDiv() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
        $("#right1").insertAfter("#left1");
        $("#right2").insertAfter("#left2");
        $("#right3").insertAfter("#left3");
        $("#right4").insertAfter("#left4");
    } else {
        // I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO WRITE HERE ^^
    }
  }
  // check when page load
  OrderDiv();  // NEW

  $(window).resize(function(){
    OrderDiv(); // check to destroy or build when we resize browser
  });

});
```

When you load with a screen size bigger than 1024px, no problem, you resize your screen under 1024px, the order of the div is well modified as I need.

But when you load under 1024px and resize up to 1024px, I would like to cancel the order and back to the basic.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: whats back to "the basic"?

Comment: You cant "cancel" it. It's likely to happen so fast you wouldn't be able to anyways. You can "revert" it afterwards with `remove` as per answers below.

Comment: @george - quite possible (I updated my comment), though I have dealt with similar questions where they literally meant "cancel", ie: "interrupt the current change" and do something to recover. Wanted to make it clear this is not a case where that line of thinking makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS to show or hide your elements and avoid JavaScript altogether. Add the elements to your HTML and then use the following CSS:

```
#right1, #right2, #right3, #right4{
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    #right1, #right2, #right3, #right4{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

If you really must use jQuery to remove and add the elements each time, your else statement would simply be:

```
} else {
    $('#right1, #right2, #right3, #right4').remove();
}
```

Comment: @georges thanks so much for your response. Actually I'm using the plugin called multiscroll.js and I'm working on the responsive. If you can have a look into the html code of this plugin you will understand why I have to change the order of the div. But I managed to do it in CSS with absolute position and top.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#right1").length) { $("#right1").remove(); // go through all of them }
```

put this in your current else stmt. 
check if that element exist, if exist remove it, else don't do anything.

Comment: @george, css is a better method, do use his instead.